# Trying to get a File.exists return true with a InputField always return false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a condition where if the file exists, then read the properties of it. My way of doing so is by having the user write an ID and, if that ID matches the file name, then it makes the conditional. However, I haven't been able to make it return true with the UserInput, however when I write the ID directly to the code it works, and I don't really know what's happening.

I tried printing both the string of the ID directly written and the InputField in the console and the results looks the same:
[Console printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a47tE.png)

And when I print the directory location with the string written in the code and with the InputField it looks like this: [File ubication and whether it exists or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEDvV.png)

I really don't know how to proceed from here and I've been stuck for quite a while now, this is the code I used (it's very simple):

```
    string path = BackupBO.Instance.DirectoryName + BackupSelected + "/" + "BBC24F4DE88E4031.txt";//UserInput en teoria
    string pathInput = BackupBO.Instance.DirectoryName + BackupSelected + "/" + UserInput.text+".txt";
    Debug.Log("Path with string literal: "+path);
    Debug.Log("Path with UserInput: " + pathInput);
    Debug.Log("Does the path with string literal exist?" + File.Exists(path));
    Debug.Log("Does the path with UserInput exist?" + File.Exists(pathInput));
```

Comment: Try logging the length of both strings. It's possible there's some non-visible whitespace there...

Comment: Have you compared the two strings? (e.g _path.Equals(pathInput);_)

Comment: How exactly do you get the user input? / Of what type is `UserInput` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [known "issue"](https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmesh-pro-ugui-hidden-characters.505493/) that there is a trailing invisible character in the `TextMeshProUGUI` component of an `TMP_InputField`. For this and other reasons you shouldn't go through the `TMP_Text` component of the input field.

You should rather directly go through the `TMP_InputField.text` property which mitigates that and contains the actual input string.

```
public TMP_InputField UserInput;
```

should solve that issue